# Froala editor image edit option now showing

Tags: javascript, froala

I was using Froala edit as rich text editor ,

```
 $(notesSelector).on('froalaEditor.initialized', function (e, editor) {
    //set original html after loading
    froalaInitialHtml = $(notesSelector).froalaEditor('html.get');
});

$(notesSelector).froalaEditor({
  key: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', '|', 'color', 'emoticons', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', '|', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent', 'quote', 'insertHR', '-', 'insertLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'insertFile', 'insertTable', 'undo', 'redo', 'clearFormatting', 'selectAll', 'html'],

  toolbarButtonsXS: ['undo', 'redo' , '-', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline','insertImage'],
  imageEditButtons:['imageInfo', 'imageAlign' ],
  toolbarSticky: true, });`
```

i was expecting image context menu , but they don't appear when image is selected

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 possible reasons why the image popup is not showing:

1. You are not including the image plugin. Make sure you include the `plugins/image.min.js` file and `plugins/image.min.css` file.
2. There are other elements on the page which have a higher `zIndex`. This is likely to happen when you are using the editor inside a modal. To overcome it, set the editor [zIndex option](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#zIndex) to a higher value.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I have the editor in Modal and using zIndex did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: zIndex fixed for me as well!

Comment: This did it for me, took me a moment to realise that it was the popup itself I had to add the zIndex to (in case anyone else is in the same situation)